# Difference between hash() and id()

Tags: python, hash, equality

I have two user-defined objects, say `a` and `b`.
Both these objects have the same `hash` values.
However, the `id(a)` and `id(b)` are unequal.

Moreover,

```
>>> a is b
False
>>> a == b
True
```

From this observation, can I infer the following?

- Unequal objects may have the same `hash` values.
- Equal objects need to have the same `id` values.
- Whenever `obj1 is obj2` is called, the `id` values of both objects is compared, not their `hash` values.

Comment: Your second inference would be easily invalidated by comparing `id(a)` and `id(b)`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks. I get it now

Comment: I wrote how hashes are calculated for built-in types [here](http://delimitry.blogspot.ru/2014/07/python-hash-calculation-algorithms.html).
You can notice that `hash` calculation for object type depends on its `id`.

Comment: This is in direct contradiction to what @Blckknght says in his answer. He says the hash calculation depends on the value contained in the object.

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary: You're misunderstanding Delimetry's comment. He's referring to the `object` type specifically when he says "object" (not objects in general). Instances of the `object` type has no value other than its identity. Nor, by default, do instances of custom classes. To give a custom class a different interpretation of "value", you need to give it an `__eq__` method (and a `__hash__` method based on the same sort of value, if you want it to be hashable).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There are three concepts to grasp when trying to understand `id`, `hash` and the `==` and `is` operators: **identity**, **value** and **hash value**. Not all objects have all three.

1. All objects have an **identity**, though even this can be a little slippery in some cases. The `id` function returns a number corresponding to an object's identity (in cpython, it returns the memory address of the object, but other interpreters may return something else). If two objects (that exist at the same time) have the same identity, they're actually two references to the same object. The `is` operator compares items by identity, `a is b` is equivalent to `id(a) == id(b)`.

   Identity can get a little confusing when you deal with objects that are cached somewhere in their implementation. For instance, the objects for small integers and strings in cpython are not remade each time they're used. Instead, existing objects are returned any time they're needed. You should not rely on this in your code though, because it's an implementation detail of cpython (other interpreters may do it differently or not at all).
2. All objects also have a **value**, though this is a bit more complicated. Some objects do not have a meaningful value other than their identity (so value an identity may be synonymous, in some cases). Value can be defined as what the `==` operator compares, so any time `a == b`, you can say that `a` and `b` have the same value. Container objects (like lists) have a value that is defined by their contents, while some other kinds of objects will have values based on their attributes. Objects of different types can sometimes have the same values, as with numbers: `0 == 0.0 == 0j == decimal.Decimal("0") == fractions.Fraction(0) == False` (yep, `bool`s are numbers in Python, for historic reasons).

   If a class doesn't define an `__eq__` method (to implement the `==` operator), it will inherit the default version from `object` and its instances will be compared solely by their identities. This is appropriate when otherwise identical instances may have important semantic differences. For instance, two different sockets connected to the same port of the same host need to be treated differently if one is fetching an HTML webpage and the other is getting an image linked from that page, so they don't have the same value.
3. In addition to a value, some objects have a **hash value**, which means they can be used as dictionary keys (and stored in `set`s). The function `hash(a)` returns the object `a`'s hash value, a number based on the object's value. The hash of an object must remain the same for the lifetime of the object, so it only makes sense for an object to be hashable if its value is immutable (either because it's based on the object's identity, or because it's based on contents of the object that are themselves immutable).

   Multiple different objects may have the same hash value, though well designed hash functions will avoid this as much as possible. Storing objects with the same hash in a dictionary is much less efficient than storing objects with distinct hashes (each hash collision requires more work). Objects are hashable by default (since their default value is their identity, which is immutable). If you write an `__eq__` method in a custom class, Python will disable this default hash implementation, since your `__eq__` function will define a new meaning of value for its instances. You'll need to write a `__hash__` method as well, if you want your class to still be hashable. If you inherit from a hashable class but don't want to be hashable yourself, you can set `__hash__ = None` in the class body.

Comment: Very thorough explanation, and I like the tip about implementing your own __hash__ method when you customize __eq__ for your own classes. Didn't know that!

Comment: Great answer! One question: the hash value is used as dictionary keys to what dictionary? A dictionary of what, a memory address location dictionary?

Comment: @bretonics: Dictionaries are a builtin data type in Python. The hashes of all keys are used to look up the values stored in the dictionary. For instance, if you create an object `o=SomeClass()` and use it as a key in a dictionary `d = {}; d[o] = something`, the hash of `o` is used internally by `d` to determine where to store `something`. You don't directly interact with the hash value at all when using the object and dictionary. At most you just have to write a `__hash__` method in `SomeClass` (which will be called automatically by the dictionary when needed).

Comment: Can we use id for hash function?

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev: yes, AFAIK it is default `__hash__` definition, but once you've defined custom `__eq__` it is ignored and none is specified

Comment: I have trouble understanding `so it only makes sense for an object to be hashable if its value is immutable` together with `Objects are hashable by default (since their default value is their identity, which is immutable)`. This seems to imply that all objects are immutable by default, which I don't think is the case.

Comment: @Blckknght Maybe what you meant to say is `**immutable** objects are hashable by default`? If you take a `list` object, for example, that is not hashable.

Comment: Lots of mutable objects are hashable still. Things like lists are mutable, but what makes them also be not hashable is that they have a customized meaning of *value* (as shown by their `__eq__` method). The "default" I'm referring to is mostly for custom object types, created by the programmer with a `class` statement. Unless you implement an `__eq__` method in the class (or inherit one from a base class), the instances of the class will be hashable by default. That's because the default meaning of value is identity, and identity is immutable even if the rest of the object is mutable.

Answer (score 7):

> Unequal objects may have the same hash values.

Yes this is true. A simple example is `hash(-1) == hash(-2)` in CPython.

> Equal objects need to have the same id values.

No this is false in general. A simple counterexample noted by @chepner is that `5 == 5.0` but `id(5) != id(5.0)`.

> Whenever, `obj1 is obj2` is called, the id values of both the objects is compared, not their hash values.

Yes this is true. `is` compares the `id` of the objects for equality (in CPython it is the memory address of the object). Generally, this has nothing to do with the object's hash value (the object need not even be hashable).

Comment: A counterexample for the 2nd assertion: `5 == 5.0` vs `id(5) == id(5.0)`.

Comment: @ajcr Even `[] is []` returns `False` even though `id([]) == id([])` returns `True`. Can you explain this too?

Comment: @chepner: That's a nicer counterexample. Mind if I steal it for the answer (with attribution, of course)?

Comment: @KshitijSaraogi Try again with `a = []` and `b = []`; the fact that `id([]) == id([])` is because the two empty list objects do not need to exist at the same time, so the id can be recycled.

Comment: @ajcr Feel free; I was going to include it in my own answer, but you covered everything I was going to.

Comment: For a dictionary lookup by key, 1st the hash is looked-up, and then if there are duplicate hashes then equality check is done. Have I got this concept right?

Comment: @variable: you're on the right track - roughly, to look up a key `K` in a dictionary the hash of `K` is computed and this hash value is used to work out the first place to check for `K` in the underlying hash table. If this item at this location is equal to `K` then the corresponding value is returned. If the item is _not_ equal to `K`, then Python jumps to a new place in the hash table and checks for equality, and the process continues. I've skipped over a few details, but that's the gist of how it works in CPython.

Answer (score 1):

The hash function is used to:

> quickly compare dictionary keys during a dictionary lookup

the ID function is used to:

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.

Comment: Why not use id for hash then?

Answer (score 0):

I just had an experiment , which assigned same whole number to 2 separated variables , but when I used ' is ' operator to compare them , then in returned True ; I didn't expect such a thing , Thought that the variables must be exact same like==>

```
a = 10
b = a
a is b # output == True
```