# module object immutable, can be used as dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary, module, immutability

I have recently read in *Learning Python 5th by Mark Lutz 2013* that python module objects are immutable, therefore they can be used as dictionary keys.

[image]

But say that I have two files `a.py` and `b.py`, I have no problem importing `b` module into `a.py` and then modify `b` module by adding property to `b` module object.

```
#a.py file 

import b
b.additionalProperty = 'hello'
```

So how is a python module object immutable and how they can be used as dictionary keys?

Comment: What is this incorrect source you refer to?

Comment: Something doesn't strictly need to be immutable to be a dictionary key. It needs to be hashable, and mutating it ought not to change its hash or its equality relation. I imagine that is true for modules...

Comment: @JonathonReinhart i have added a reference to the source

Comment: @khelwood could you expand on the concept a bit more? more specifically, if I add a property to `b` module e.g. `b.additionalProperty = 'hello'`, will this change the `b` module's hash or equality relation? is the `b` module no longer immutable?

Comment: @Thor You can try that out easily enough, and no, adding custom properties to a module does not affect its hash or its equality relation. There is no real reason why it should.

Comment: @khelwood do you mind if i ask, how is the hash value for module object calculated? could you please explain it in a bit more depth, or provide me with a pointer to a reliable source of information that i can have a read? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making a change to a module object (such as adding or modifying values in its global namespace) doesn't change its hash value. So while it's not immutable by any normal definition, it's "value" for hashing purposes is its identity, which *is* immutable.

So you can indeed use a module object as a key for a dictionary. You can also use instances of custom classes, like this one:

```
class Example:
    pass # no __hash__ or __eq__ defined

obj = Example()
d = {obj: "this works"}
print(d)

obj.foo = "the attributes of obj don't matter for the hash"
d[obj] = "so this overwrites the previous value in the dict"
print(d)
```

Comment: hi Blckknght, thank you very much for the explanation. Do you mind if I ask, why adding or modifying values in a module's global namespace doesn't change its hash value? Put it another way, how is the hash value for module object calculated? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: That's just the way modules are implemented. The Python developers could have designed it differently, but there is probably no good reason to do so. As I showed with the `Example` class, the default hash value for objects is not based on contents (it's based on identity instead). Only numbers and containers have different meanings for value (and hash value) in most cases. [This question from a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34402522/difference-between-hash-and-id) (and my answer to it) may be useful to you if you want to understand this better.

Comment: thank you so much for helping out! really appreciate it! :)